# html/css buttons that scroll down to different div sections on a webpage

Tags: css, html, button, scroll

Can someone help me I'm searching for `css/html` code example:

I have a webpage with 3 buttons(top, middle, bottom) each specified to 1 div section on my page, lets say my first div section is in the middle of that page `div id='middle'`.

If I click this button(middle) my page would automatically scroll down from the top 
of my page to the `div #middle` section.

same for the other buttons refered to div `id='top'`, and div `id='bottom'`

Thanks in forward! I really couldnt find any solution on the internet.

Is there a way to keep my buttonlist on a fixed position so it stays on screen while
moving through sections?

Comment: Are you looking for an animated scroll that requires JavaScript, or the standard jump behavior caused by bookmark anchors?

Comment: I needed a simple jump action, but someone already gave me the answer thanks thou.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For something really basic use this:

```
<a href="#middle">Go To Middle</a>
```

Or for something simple in javascript check out this jQuery plugin [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). Quite useful for scrolling smoothly.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Please select the answer?

Answer (score 61):

try this:

```
<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('middle').scrollIntoView();" />
```

Comment: Much better, @Magicode it also applies to divs and almost all other elements.

Comment: can we do that on class? class='middle'

Comment: @jned29 classes are expected to be commonly used in multiple elements. It is not a good idea.

Comment: Sadly, browser support still is a little weak, especially if you want to use the 'smooth' option. http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: brilliant answer..it isn't mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 38):

There is a much easier way to get the smooth scroll effect without javascript. 
In your CSS just target the entire html tag and give it scroll-behavior: smooth;

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
 
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 } 
 
 #down {
  margin-top: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <a href="#down">Click Here to Smoothly Scroll Down</a>
  <div id="down">
    <h1>You are down!</h1>
  </div>
</html
```

The "scroll-behavior" is telling the page how it should scroll and is so much easier than using javascript. Javascript will give you more options on speed and the smoothness but this will deliver without all of the confusing code.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for this! Helped me with my site :)

Answer (score 15):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
<a href="#middle">Middle</a>
<a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
<div id="top"><a href="top"></a>Top</div>
<div id="middle"><a href="middle"></a>Middle</div>
<div id="bottom"><a href="bottom"></a>Bottom</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top,#middle,#bottom{
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    background: green; 
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/x4wDk/

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use `id="top"` for the last 3?

Comment: @steebchen, Nooo... that would completely break the program since the first link would be linked to 3 elements instead of one, and the other links would do nothing.

Comment: @edwardtyl I don't know why I wrote this comment.. I'm sure I meant something different, but I don't remember ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#To top">Scroll to top</a>
```

If you want smooth scrolling:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution to solve this by far.