# How to make a button scroll down page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Couldn't find a tutorial for this anywhere or just didn't use the right keywords.
I'm making a one-paged website, and I'd like the navigation bar buttons to scroll the page up/down to the right part. 
Would this be possible in just HTML and CSS?
I'm not so experienced with JavaScript.

Similar to ''Scroll to the top'' but that I could decide to where it scrolls the page, like middle, top, bottom etc. .

Comment: possible duplicate of [html/css buttons that scroll down to different div sections on a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349490/html-css-buttons-that-scroll-down-to-different-div-sections-on-a-webpage)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** There is now a better way to use this, using the HTML `id` attribute:

Set the destination id: `<h1 id="section1">Section 1</h1>`

And create a link to that destination using the anchor tag: `<a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>`

The benefit of this new method is that the `id` attribute can be set on any HTML element. You don't have to wrap superfluous anchor tags around destination links anymore!

**Original answer:**

You can look at using the HTML anchor tag.

`<a name="section1">Section 1</a>`

alongside

`<a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>`

When the user clicks on "Go to section 1", they will be sent to the section of the page where the "Section 1" text is displayed.

Comment: In addition, check out [this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) to animate the scroll, rather than just jumping the user there instantly

Comment: Another question here then. How could I make my JS image slideshow start when the user scrolls to it's location? Now it's just running there as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: You'll want to detect whether the element is visible on the page or not. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 2):

using `window.scrollTo` you can scroll down your page like this

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```