# Button_to scroll down to specific section

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

At the top of the user's profile I have this button:

```
<%= button_to 'Make a detailed enquiry', user_path(@user), :class=>"enquirySection", :method => :get %>
```

Then at the very bottom of the page I am rendering a form in which the viewer can make an enquiry:

```
    <div class="enquirySection">
      <%= render "enquiries/form" %>
    </div>
```

I want the user to be scrolled down to this form when (s)he clicks on the button so I added the ":class=>"enquirySection"" and "div class="enquirySection"". It doesn't work.

I tried something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797139/how-to-make-a-button-scroll-down-page-in-html) to that but I think it does not related to my case.

Any clue of how is this done in Rails with button_to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a class, but an `id`

try

```
<%= button_to 'Make a detailed enquiry', user_path(@user, anchor: :enquirySection), :method => :get %>
```

or simply

```
<%= link_to 'Make a detailed enquiry', user_path(@user, anchor: 'enquirySection) %>
```

and then

```
<div id="enquirySection">
 <%= render "enquiries/form" %>
</div>
```

would do the job.

Comment: indeed, you are right on using id file, thanks a lot