# My 2 Div's keep overlaping

Tags: html, css, button, scroll

Tried to follow other similar questions here, but i cant find a solution for my problem.

I have 2 divs, the first one is full-screen with a button on the bottom of the page that when i click it, will scroll down to the other div. But what keeps happening to me is the 2 divs overlapping.

```css
    header{
     background-image: url("../img/img_header_mobile.jpg");
     background-position: top center;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     float: left;
    }
    
    .imagem-menu{
     width: 321px;
     height: 569px;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .botao-scroll{
     background: url("../img/botao_scroll.png");
     border: none;
     background-size: 60px 60px;
     background-color: none;
     margin-left: 7px;
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 5%;
    }
    
    #slidepassos{
    height: 667px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    
    }
```

```html
   
    <header>
        <a href="#slidepassos" class="botao-scroll"></a>
        <div class="imagem-menu"></div>
        </header>
    <div id="slidepassos" ="slidepassos"><a href="slidepassos">
     side com passos</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include your Javascript that does the button click?

Comment: Code Snippet please

Comment: Your question is not too clear. In addition to showing more HTML (with the second div, which seems to be missing from your code), can you explain in more detail what you want to happen?

Comment: @Mr Lister Yeah, sorry, it was missing the second div code.

Comment: @DominicValenciana The button is actually just an <a> into an image.

Comment: @myfingershurt Okay, can you show us the Javascript that handles the routing for your `a` tag.

Comment: @DominicValenciana Theres no javascript there, i used this information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349490/html-css-buttons-that-scroll-down-to-different-div-sections-on-a-webpage and tried to implement it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya its missing the second div. I expect it will be after header
try this one

```css
header{
    background-image: url("../img/img_header_mobile.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
}

.imagem-menu{
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid yellow;
    width: 321px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.botao-scroll{
  z-index:2;
    background: url("../img/botao_scroll.png");
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-color: none;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
}
.botao-scroll:hover
{
  color: red;
}

#slidepassos{
  position:relative;
height: 667px;
width: 100%;
background: green;
float: left;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
<a href="#slidepassos" class="botao-scroll">
  scroll down
</a>
<div class="imagem-menu"></div>
</header>
<div id="slidepassos">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: it worked. Can you just explain me what was the main problem in the code? Thank you :)

Comment: if the 2nd div is after header. the header must has 'real height' (in this case i use 100vh instead of 100%) and set the position to relative

regards

Comment: Hum, ok. Thank you for the help.