# How to make a go down button? So when clicking it will redirect me a dew pixels down

Tags: html, css

So I have this small icon and I want it to go down a little just enough to cover the entire part of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ0U6.png), you click on it, and it moves you smoothly to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ0U6.png). How do I code that?[image: So I click the circle]

[image: and it gets me here]

[image: which is basically a few pixels away]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349490/html-css-buttons-that-scroll-down-to-different-div-sections-on-a-webpage
you can see in here, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

give the next element to the arrow some id for example if it's a div, add this to it:

```
<div id="header">some content...</div>
```

the wrap the arrow inside an anchor tag and give it the id of the element you want to go to like this :

```
<a href="#header">
   <p>Go down </p> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS implementation:**

```
window.scrollTo(0, 50);
```

or

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 50, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

where 50 is amount of pixels. [Link to MDN Window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Scroll to particular element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("box");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

[Link to MDN ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)